# Add a Paypal button IMAGE to my custom PayPal checkout code?

Tags: html, paypal

I have the following code but unlike the code generated on the Paypal button generator, this does not show a image as a button; only text.

I'm not using the hosted button solution, but my method is supported, I just can't figure out how to make the button show an image (preferably the 'Buy Now') instead of just the plain text.

Is there a tag I missed somewhere?

```
<form target="_blank" class="paypal-button" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="<?=$serverFullDesc?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?=$costMonth_step1?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2"value="Initial Server Build (one-time)">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="<?=$buildPrice?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3"value="<?=$maintPlan?> - invoiced monthly">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="<?=$maintPlanPrice?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$gTotalPayment?>">
    <input value="buynow" name="button" type="hidden">
    <input value="_cart" name="cmd" type="hidden">
    <input  name="upload" value="1" type="hidden">
    <input value="<?=$currency?>" name="currency_code" type="hidden">
    <input value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" name="business" type="hidden">
    <input value="www" name="env" type="hidden">

    <button class="paypal-button large" type="submit">Buy Now</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button for Buy Now has the classes "paypal-button large" Where is the CSS for paypal-button coming from? That's what you need.

Comment: Well spotted. That is actually legacy code that I'd overlooked! It was originally included by a JavaScript Paypal Buttons library that I was using to create the code until I figured that it had too many limitations. I could use a similar method if I could get image from somewhere for that to link to after adding the classes in my CSS. Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the actual image. Also, I'm wondering what the 'usual' way of doing this is?

Comment: You can just get an image with a google image search and then just use that?